# Riemann theory of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

In Arnold Sommerfeld's Lecture Vol.IV, it is mentioned that as per Riemann's theory of functions 
 *"If a two dimensional potential $v$ vanishes together with its normal derivative along a finite curve segment then $v$ vanishes identically in the whole plane".*

I think this is somehow related to the uniqueness theorem.

Would you kindly suggest me how to prove this or from where I can get the proof/ relevant discussion on this statement?

Comment: Did you mean an harmonic (real) potential on $\Bbb{R}^2\cong \Bbb{C}$ ? If so it is the real part of a complex analytic function $f$, say your finite curve segment is $[a,b]$, your assumption is that $\Re(f(z)),\Re(i f'(z))$ both vanish on it which implies $f'(z) =(\Re(f(z))' -i \Re(if'(z))=0$ on $[a,b]$ thus $f' = 0$ everywhere so that $\Re(f)$ is constant $ = 0$

Comment: Yes, sir. this is a harmonic potential which satisfies the laplace's equation or helmholtz equation. Would you please mention any reference or book from where I can go through the details on it.

Comment: The main point is that if a complex analytic function vanishes on some segment (or curve) then it vanishes everywhere, and that the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel / harmonic conjugate / Cauchy integral formula implies your harmonic function is the real part of a complex analytic function.

Comment: Thank you Sir, for your kind cooperation. If I face any any problem, I shall ask you.

Comment: Sir, you wrote that "f ′(z)=(R(f(z))′−iR(if ′(z))=0 on [a,b] thus f ′=0 everywhere ". Would you kindly tell me once again how to prove that if f ' (z)=0 on a finite line segment inside a domain D; then f ' (z)=0 everywhere in that domain.

Comment: If $g$ is analytic and non-constant then locally $g(z) = g(a)+C (z-a)^n+O((z-a)^{n+1})$ so its zeros are isolated and it can't vanish on a curve passing through $a$